# Trying to render different models on Layout and view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model in the Layout.cshtml of type **PeriodIndexModel**. I use this model to dynamically fill a sidebar menu.

Then in the same Layout I have de main tag with this inside:

```
<div class="col-lg-10 bg-light">
    <div class="container" >
          <main role="main" class="pb-3" style="height:100vh">
              @RenderBody()
          </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click a button from the sidebar menu, this executes an action from a controller like this:

```
<a class="link-body-emphasis d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded"
   asp-area="" asp-controller="Expense" asp-action="GetExpenses"
>
    @period.PeriodText
</a>
```

What is happening is that GetExpenses action, renders a View who has a model of type **ExpenseListModel** so when I try to render the view with that model I get an error of:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsumoFE.WebPage.Models.ExpenseListModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConsumoFE.WebPage.Models.PeriodIndexModel]'.

I know this is happening because the Layout page is trying to render a PeriodIndexModel but now I'm sending a ExpenseListModel.
I need that the RenderBody, only renders the page requested by the clic on the action of the sidebar but I don't know how to make that.

Comment: Have your models implement interfaces matching what views require.

Comment: No, I didnt did that. Can u pass me some page so i can see how i can do that?